# Shopify.ruby-lsp VSCode Extension vs. Other VSCode Ruby Extensions

Tags: ruby-debug-ide, ruby-lsp

I just came across the [Shopify.ruby-lsp vscode extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/ruby), which works with [VSCode RDBG](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KoichiSasada.vscode-rdbg). I have been using the rebornix.Ruby / vscode-ruby extension and ruby-debug-ide; Stafford Brunk (wingrunr21, the developer of vscode-ruby) is asking for someone else to take over that project.

It would be helpful to understand how the various packages provided by Shopify for Ruby programming compare to packages from others. I am not so worried about feature-level comparisons, right now, I would just like to know the answers to very basic questions like:

- How much of rebornix vscode-ruby / vscode-solargraph / ruby-debug-ide  is addressed by Shopify.ruby-lsp / VSCode RDBG? In other words, can I swap out some or all of the other stuff and use Shopify.ruby-lsp for the same purpose?
- What other packages might conflict with Shopify.ruby-lsp, and should be disabled or removed?